# how to define byte array in Nemerle

Tags: nemerle

```
def cmd = array [ 0x0F, 0x03 ]
```

this code defines array of integers so I want array of bytes

interesting that

```
def cmd = array [ 0x0Fb, 0x03b ]
```

this code defines the same...

how to define byte array instead of int array here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def cmd = array [ 0x0F : byte, 0x03 ]
```

and modifiers doesn't work for hex so far.